# 'k_means' object has no attribute 'k'

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, machine-learning-model

Why is it showing an error of AttributeError: 'k_means' object has no attribute 'k'? I believed the line self.k = k (line 15) initialized the attribute k.

This is an online example I was following, I am using Google colaboratory in Python 3.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[1,3]])
plt.scatter(x[:,0],x[:,1],s=150)
plt.show()
color = 10*["g.","r.","c.","b.","k."]


class kmeans():

  def __init__(self, k = 2, tol = .001, max_iteration = 200):
    self.k = k
    self.tol = tol
    self.iter = max_iteration
  
  def fit(self,data):

    self.centroids = {}
    for i in range(self.k):
     self.centroids[i] = data[i]
  
    for i in range(self.max_iteration):
     self.classifications = {}
  
    for i in range(self.k):
     self.classifications[i] = []
    
  for featureset in data:
    distances = [np.linalg.norm(featureset-self.centriods[centroid]) for centroid in self.centroids]
    classification = distances.index(min(distances))
    self.classifications[classification].append(featureset)
    previous_centroids = dict(self.centroids)
    
    for classifications in self.classificaitons:
      self.centroids[classifications] = np.average(self.classificaitons[classifications], axis=0)
      
    optimixed = True
    
    for c in self.centroids:
      origional_centroid = previous_centroids[c]
      current_centroid = self.centroids[c]
      if np.sum((current_centroid - origional_centroid)/origional_centroid*100.0) > self.tol:
        
        optimized = False
        
        if optimized:
          break
```

### end of fit

```
 def predict(self,data):

distances = [np.linalg.norm(featureset-self.centriods[centroid]) for centroid in self.centroids]
classification = distances.index(min(distances))
return classification
```

clf = k_means()
clf.fit(x)

I expect the output result to show some clusters of the coordinates in line 6 when I call kmeans, but I cannot get past this error. (I plan on widening the dataset once this issue is resolved, these 3 coordinates were just used for practice). Please excuse the formatting of the code in the post.

Comment: Why don't you fix the formatting of the code? And the typos in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You probably call an old version of your code.

Because `k_means` is not the same as `kmeans`.

90% correct is not enough for programming. You need to work more precisely. A compiled language may be a better choice for you to find errors earlier, and python notebooks may be a poor choice for a beginner because of the hidden state of the runtime environment.

Comment: Sorry. I was trying to find a solution for the issue and took out the underscore. Putting it back and having continuity between the class name and calling it still did not fix the issue.

Comment: "AttributeError: 'k_means' object has no attribute 'k'" is still presenting as the error.

Comment: In which line? We can't see the error message. And update the question with the fixed version, and fix the formatting, please! *Reinitialize your notebook* to get rid of such artefacts.